# What is the "gauntlet" start system for character creation?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, terminology

A while back in a stat discussion, someone mentioned that they used something called a "gauntlet" start for character creation. It was a post on Reddit, either for *Kingmaker* or regular *Pathfinder*.

I remember him saying that it made his stat array fixed to the point where he couldn’t even choose what went where, and he wanted advice on what class to pick as a result. Multiple people in the comments acknowledged its existence and a few even brought up their opinions on the system.

Sadly I can’t find anything on it, yet my curiosity is getting the best of me. There was a massive amount of equipment and unarmed strike stuff when I googled it, but in spite of excluding all that stuff I couldn’t find what I needed. (The post I saw originally did not mention equipment at any point, gauntlet or otherwise.)

What is the "gauntlet" start system for character creation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [this Reddit post](https://reddit.com/r/dndnext/comments/4s94op/gauntlet_style_character_creation/) the term "gauntlet style" is tied to a practice also known as a character funnel, in which the players begin the campaign by running multiple randomly generated characters through a high-lethality scenario, with the survivors forming the pool of potential player characters for the remainder of the campaign.

In some forms of this method, the characters being funneled are "level zero" characters who have yet to be assigned to a particular class.